# Проблема с наследованием интерфейсов

Tags: c#, .net, language-lawyer

Почему при компиляции этого:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Lol l = new Lol();
    Console.WriteLine(((IParent)l).Family);
    Console.WriteLine(((IChild)l).Family);
    Console.WriteLine(l.Name);
  }
}

public interface IParent
{
  string Family { get; }
}

public interface IChild : IParent
{
  string Name { get; }
}

public class Lol : IChild
{
  string IParent.Family { get { return "suck"; } }
  string IChild.Family { get { return "duck"; } }
  public string Name { get { return "ross"; } }
}
```

IdeOne выдает это:

**prog.cs(27,26): error CS0550: `Lol.IChild.Family.get` is an accessor not found in interface member `IChild.Family`
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings**

Comment: В зависимости от желаемого результата придется либо удалить IChild.Family из Lol, либо избавиться от наследования интерфейсов.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Дело в том, что у класса может быть лишь одна имплементация метода/свойства интерфейса. Интерфейс — лишь «обещание» имплементировать те или иные методы/свойства, а наследованный интерфейс — лишь более сильное обещание. У вас объявление `class Lol : IChild` есть обещание имплементировать все методы/свойства интерфейса `IChild` (то есть, в вашем случае, `Name`), а также все методы/свойства родительского интерфейса `IParent`.

Свойство `Family` интерфейса `IChild` унаследовано от интерфейса `IParent`, таким образом в интерфейса `IChild` содержится не два, а только одно свойство `Family`. Разрешение имплементировать как `IParent.Family`, так и `IChild.Family`, привело бы к *двум* различным имплементациям *одного и того же* свойства. При этом компилятор не знал бы, какое из них использовать.

Поэтому строчка

```
string IChild.Family { get { return "duck"; } }
```

не пропускается компилятором.

---

Формально, запрещение можно найти в спецификации языка (которая находится в каталоге `<тут каталог Visual Studio>\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx`), в разделе 13.4.1 *Explicit interface member implementations*. Там разобран именно ваш случай:

> The fully qualified name of an interface member must reference the interface in which the member was declared. Thus, in the declarations
>
> ```
> interface IControl
> {
>     void Paint();
> }
> interface ITextBox: IControl
> {
>     void SetText(string text);
> }
> class TextBox: ITextBox
> {
>     void IControl.Paint() {...}
>     void ITextBox.SetText(string text) {...}
> }
> ```
>
> the explicit interface member implementation of `Paint` must be written as `IControl.Paint`.

Comment: т.е. иными словами, у интерфейсов не наследование а агрегация? получается так, потому что я например не вижу проблемы в выборе метода, если он реализован явно, все равно такой метод можно вызвать только приведя объект к типу интерфейса. И в самом классе такой же метод может быть реальзован вообще третьим способом, при неявной реализации интерфейса. Не возникает же проблемы когда в наличии как явная, так и неявная реализации одного и того же интерфейса

Comment: @rdorn: Ну, не то, чтобы совсем агрегация: http://pastebin.com/5NG5N04a. При агрегации нужно было бы по идее _две_ функции `G`. Хотя с другой стороны: http://pastebin.com/ATZU0H56

Comment: вот и я о чем. Если уж наследование, то по-честному, можно реализовать и родителя и потомка полностью явно, серьезных проблем для этого я не вижу, разве что где-то в реализации самих интерфейсов как таковых. При неявной реализации формально контракт выполняется при единственной реализации метода, не зависимо от количества интерфейсов его требующих, собственно так и работает сейчас. А вот в явной реализацией, на мой взгляд, накосячили, но мне это пока не мешает =) агрегация так агрегация.